# MySQL - How do you set a local variable inside of a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how to update a local variable while inside of a SELECT statement. There are many versions of this that use "user" variables - but those are deprecated.

For example, this is what I have right now - and the output is always zero. I get that the equal sign is an equality check versus an assignment operator. But if I try to add ":=" I get a syntax error.

```
DECLARE v_row_num INT;
SET v_row_num = 0;

SELECT (v_row_num = v_row_num + 1) AS player_rank
--theres more to this query FYI
```

The old way (with user variables) is simple:

```
SET @v_row_num = 0;

SELECT (@v_row_num := @v_row_num + 1) AS player_rank
--theres more to this query FYI
```

Is there something like this for "local" variables?

Comment: Have you come across window functions? eg https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank

Comment: Only user-defined variables allows inline value assign. Hence local variable cannot be used in this case - use intermediate user-defined variable (and then assign its value to local variable if needed).

Comment: @P.Salmon that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :) I thought I read on a post somewhere that MySQL didn't have "ROW_NUMBER" as others do... Turns out I need to read better. If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Akina this would also work. I like the idea that P.Salmon had though as it may be a little cleaner. (Then again I'm pretty new to MySQL so I'm not sure). Either way thanks for your time :)